# How can I level up my AI crew?

Tags: x4-foundations

When you try to set default behaviors for AI-controlled craft in X4:Foundations, you'll see that the Default Behavior button brings up a list of tasks with a number of stars next to each. For example, Automine requires a pilot with one star while Explore requires a three star pilot.

In X3, you could start a pilot trading in sector. After a while, the ability to auto-trade throughout the galaxy would become available. In X4 (as of version 1.50), it doesn't seem to be possible to tell low level pilots to auto-trade in sector. I'm stuck telling them what to do and where.

How do I level up pilots to get those stars?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I level up pilots to get those stars?

Following [this forum thread](https://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?f=182&t=406105), it appears that the answer simply is

- "have them fly things around" or
- "use a more advanced pilot to set the default behaviour, then swap to an unexperienced pilot "

The latter seems like an oversight by the developers and will likely be patched out.
So it would appear that the most "efficient" way to train unexperienced pilots is to either manually command them around until they have enough experience or have a dedicated miner that will just train new pilots with auto-mining until they can auto-trade.

But then, if you have money, you can just buy a new ship at a dock and immediately sell it (but not the auto-equipped pilot!) as those tend to have the necessary 3 stars for auto-trading by default...

Comment: That forum thread seems to be a bit dated (which is funny for a game that has been out for *days*). I don't think you can tell low level pilots to autotrade at all anymore. The "high level default behavior" cheat also seems like something that will get patched away.

Comment: @Axiom To level up pilots you could also buy a miner and have the newbie pilot auto-mine until they have they have the experience points to auto-trade.